# Suppress mesage-The Mapping task failed to run. Another instance of the task is currently running

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I have set up multiple jobs in Informatica cloud to sync data from Oracle with Informatica objects. The job is scheduled to run every 3 minutes as per the business requirements. Sometimes the job used to run long due to secure agent resource crunch and my team used to multiple emails as below

```
The Mapping task failed to run. Another instance of the task is currently running.
```

Is there any way to suppress these failure emails in the mapping?

Answer (score 0):

This wont get set at the mapping level but on the session or integration service level see following https://network.informatica.com/thread/7312

Comment: This answer is not helpful at all, OP states he uses Informatica cloud

Answer (score 0):

This type of error comes when workflow/session is running and trying to re-run. use check if by script if already running then wait. If want to run multiple instance of same:

In Workflow Properties Enable 'Configure Concurrent Execution' by checking the check box.

once its enables you 2 options

1. Allow Concurrent Run with same instance name
2. Allow Concurrent run only with unique instance name

Comment: This answer is not helpful at all, OP states he uses Informatica cloud

Answer (score 0):

Notifications configured at the task level over ride those at the org level, so you could do this by configuring notifications at the task level and only sending out warnings to the broader list. That said, some people should still be receiving the error level warning because if it recurs multiple times within a short period of time there may be another issue.

Another thought is that batch processes that run every three minutes that take longer than three minutes is usually an opportunity to improve the design. Often a business requirement for short batch intervals is around a "near real time" desire. If you have also Cloud Application Integration service, you may want to set up an event to trigger the batch run. If there is still overlap based on events, you can use the Cloud Data Integration API to and create a dynamic version of the task each time. For really simple integrations you could perform the integration in CAI, which does allow multiple instances running at the same time.

HTH